# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!' reactjs mainchunk.js

Tags: reactjs

I am learning reactjs I have made components from a html template, when I am calling them I am receiving this error:

> class App extends !(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module './components'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }())

Please any one let me know why this is occurring

```
**App.js** 
import React from 'react';
import Component from './components';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import About from './components/about';
import Blog from './components/blog';
import Contact from './components/contact';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Home from './components/home';
import Menus from './components/menus';
import Projects from './components/projects';
import Reasearch from './components/reasearch';
import Services from './components/services';
import Testimonials from './components/testimonials';
import Welcome from './components/welcome';

class App extends Component {
 render() {
 return (
  <div id="colorlib-page">
    <div id="container-wrap">
    <Menus></Menus>
    <Welcome></Welcome>
    <Welcome></Welcome>
    <Services></Services>
    <Reasearch></Reasearch>     
    <Projects></Projects>
    <About></About>
    <Testimonials></Testimonials>
    <Blog></Blog>
    <Contact></Contact>
    <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}
export default App;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Arvind Pundir - A Fullstack Web & App Developer</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:200,300,400,600,700,800,900" 
rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/animate.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/magnific-popup.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/aos.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/ionicons.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/flaticon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/icomoon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/css/style.css">
```

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

<div id="root"></div>



 <!-- loader -->
 <div id="ftco-loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"> 
<circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/> 
<circle class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" 
stroke="#F96D00"/></svg></div>


<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
 <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/aos.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/scrollax.min.js"></script>  
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line of code:

```
import Component from './components';
```

Notice that this is a directory for most of your other component imports:

```
import About from './components/about';
import Blog from './components/blog';
import Contact from './components/contact';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import Home from './components/home';
import Menus from './components/menus';
import Projects from './components/projects';
import Reasearch from './components/reasearch';
import Services from './components/services';
import Testimonials from './components/testimonials';
import Welcome from './components/welcome';
```

If you don't give an exact path to a component within your `./components` directory there needs to be an `index.js` file within your `./components` directory for the `import Component from './components';` to work correctly. You can see this from your error message:

> class App extends !(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module './components'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }())

This is telling you it can't find the `./components` module associate with the `import Component from './components';` import. Either add an `index.js` file within your `./components` directory containing the necessary code for said component or double check that your path is correct for said import, i.e.:

```
import Component from './components'<COMPONENT>;
```

where `<COMPONENT>` is the name of the component you meant to import.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: great what code I should keep in index.js file, I am php developer just trying to move on react

Comment: I got this , I was using this "import React from 'react';" now i changed it to "import React, { Component } from 'react';"

Comment: If you don't have a true use case for said import you can just remove that statement. It's more of a pattern you can use if desired. Some people will have an `index.js` file to act as a "container" like component which they will use to compose the other components within the same directory. The benefit is you can just import `./containers` later on since the `index.js` file took care of the imports within that directory. Currently you're importing each specific module from the `./containers` directory which is fine, it's just a matter of personal preference. I'd just remove that statement

Comment: The `import Component from './components';` statement is looking for a `index.js` file within that directory as stated in the answer. Looks like you meant to destructure Component from React instead, so just remove the statement and change to: `import React, { Component } from 'react';`

Comment: Can you please tell me, index.js code, I think I will need to import all component in index.js file , am I right?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can just import components as they're needed. This is currently what you're doing and seems more appropriate. If your `Blog` component was using multiple components related to the blog page you could have an `index.js` file which would import the subcomponents and structure them as appropriate. It's hard to give exact code since it depends on each particular use case and what you're trying to do. Short answer there isn't one correct way to do it.

Comment: For more information checkout this link: https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-100-correct-way-to-structure-a-react-app-or-why-theres-no-such-thing-3ede534ef1ed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201283/discussion-between-nathan-and-arvindpundir).